# How to configure pam in linux such  that the login id and password should not be same?

Tags: linux, pam

How to configure pam in linux such  that the login id and password should not be same?

Comment: This belongs on serverfault.com really.

Comment: No, it doesn't. At least, I think it doesn't. I can't figure out what it's asking, though...

Comment: It's a very, very confused person that originally asked one question but refuses to open a new question for a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Install passwdqc module in the next way using Ubuntu:

```
$sudo apt-get install libpam-passwdqc
```

After that, modifies the /etc/pam.d/common-password file adding the next line at the begining:

```
password        requisite       pam_passwdqc.so config=/etc/passwdqc.conf
```

And add to /etc/passwdqc.conf file:

```
similar=deny
```